JSDoc not generating the documentation correctly in Vue 3
I made a simple app in Vue 3 and i'm trying to use JSdoc to make the documentation of my code, but when im trying to generate it, the index.html file is empty. I've tried to debug the command but i does'nt throw any error, here is the config file of JSdoc and the index.html file that generates.
jsdoc.conf.json
{
  "source": {
    "include": ["src/views/"],
    "includePattern": "\\.(vue|js)$",
    "excludePattern": "(node_modules/|docs)"
  },
  "opts": {
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "./docs"
  },
  "plugins": ["plugins/markdown", "node_modules/jsdoc-vuejs"],
  "templates": {
    "cleverLinks": false,
    "monospaceLinks": false
  }
}

Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JSDoc: Home</title>

    <script src="scripts/prettify/prettify.js"> </script>
    <script src="scripts/prettify/lang-css.js"> </script>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/prettify-tomorrow.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jsdoc-default.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="main">

    <h1 class="page-title">Home</h1>

    



    


    <h3> </h3>










    









</div>

<nav>
    <h2><a href="index.html">Home</a></h2>
</nav>

<br class="clear">

<footer>
    Documentation generated by <a href="https://github.com/jsdoc/jsdoc">JSDoc 4.0.3</a> on Sat May 11 2024 13:50:02 GMT+0200 (hora de verano de Europa central)
</footer>

<script> prettyPrint(); </script>
<script src="scripts/linenumber.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>


I have no experience with JSdoc but this might be a good start? https://github.com/Kocal/jsdoc-vuejs#readme
